# Calling On-Screen Keyboard from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pull up the on-screen keyboard.
Here are my attempts so far:

```
' Only needed for Test3
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _ 
ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub Test1()
    ' Run-time error'53':
    ' File Not found
    Dim RetVal As Variant
    RetVal = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\system32\osk.exe", 1)
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    ' Run-time error '432':
    ' File name or class name not found during Automation operation
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe"
End Sub

Sub Test3()
    ' No error. Nothing happens at all
    ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, "osk.exe", vbNullString, "C:\", 1
End Sub
```

Test2 from [this forum](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/930128-opening-on-screen-keyboard-in-windows-8-using-vba.html).
Test3 from [this forum](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-34397.html).

I checked the path to osk.exe is correct.
I have a Surface laptop/tablet, so it has a touch screen and a "touch" keyboard (different from the osk). Is that what's causing the issue or possibly it's a Windows 10 thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 64-Bit OS try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal Enable As Boolean) As Boolean

Private Sub RunOsk_on64Bit()
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection False
    ShellExecute 0, "open", "osk.exe", "", "C:\windows\system32\osk.exe", SW_SHOWNORMAL 
    Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection True
End Sub
```

Found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e9252bb7-1df0-4826-880f-ad0a636a18cd/error-when-opening-onscreen-keyboard-in-windows-7-could-not-start-onscreen-keyboard?forum=vbgeneral), this might the explanation, quote from the link

> > This is an issue with 64-bit OS, it affects any 64-bit version of Windows.
>
> Basically you are calling osk.exe, but your program you are calling it
>   from is a 32-bit app. Windows won't allow you to call a 64-bit OSK.exe
>   from your program. The comments appear to miss your point here, anyone
>   can start osk.exe from Run, but call it from within a 32-bit
>   application won't work in 64-bit Windows.
>
> I am developing software that uses the on-screen keyboard, the only
>   work around is Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection.

**Update**: A "nicer" version might look like that

```
Option Explicit

Type SHELLEXECUTEINFO
    cbSize As Long
    fMask As Long
    hwnd As Long
    lpVerb As String
    lpFile As String
    lpParameters As String
    lpDirectory As String
    nShow As Long
    hInstApp As Long
    lpIDList As Long
    lpClass As String
    hkeyClass As Long
    dwHotKey As Long
    hIcon As Long
    hProcess As Long
End Type

Public Declare Function ShellExecuteEx Lib "shell32.dll" _
                                       (lpExecInfo As SHELLEXECUTEINFO) As Long


Declare Function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByRef ptr As Long) As Boolean
Declare Function Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByRef ptr As Long) As Boolean


Public Function KeyboardOpen()
  Dim shInfo As SHELLEXECUTEINFO
  Dim lngPtr As Long

   With shInfo
      .cbSize = Len(shInfo)
      .lpFile = "C:\Windows\Sysnative\cmd.exe" 'best to use Known folders here
      .lpParameters = "/c start osk.exe"
      .lpDirectory = "C:\windows\system32" 'best to use Known folders here
      .lpVerb = "open"
      .nShow = 0
   End With
   Call Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(lngPtr)
   Call ShellExecuteEx(shInfo)
   Call Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(lngPtr)
End Function
```

Based on the information in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365744.aspx) it might be more reliable to use Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection and Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection functions instead.

Comment: For those using  64 bit change to  Private Declare PtrSafe

Comment: @QHarr: If you work with a 64-bit version of Excel then you need to adjust it, not if you work with 32-bit Excel on a 64-bit Windows

Comment: This works perfectly! I did check, and I am running 32-bit Excel, so I take it that was the issue. Although now I have to figure out how to close it, which I understand is quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: Why sholud it be more difficult to terminate osk.exe?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Control_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    strInput = "C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-osk_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.3636_none_1f546a300f4325b7\OSK.Exe"
    Application.FollowHyperlink strInput, , True
   


End Sub
```