# How do I update cmd.exe called from VBA Shell or WScript.Shell?

Tags: vba, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wscript.shell

I'd like to update the command prompt called from VBA shell or WScript.Shell command and start wsl.exe.
This is because wsl.exe is not included in the command prompt called by shell or WScript.Shell.

[image]

```
Sub Sample1()
    Dim WSH, wExec, sCmd, Result As String

    Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    sCmd = "dir c:\Windows\System32\ws*.exe"
    Set wExec = WSH.Exec("%ComSpec% /c " & sCmd)

    Do While wExec.Status = 0
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Result = wExec.StdOut.ReadAll

    MsgBox Result

    Set wExec = Nothing
    Set WSH = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The code is working as I would I expect it to work. You run the `dir` command and get all the file names back in `Result`. So, what would you like to do or what do you expect?

Comment: The black screen shows that cmd.exe was started from windows10.  If you execute the dir command in c: \ Windows \ system32, you will find wsl.exe.  However, as shown in the white screen, when cmd.exe is started from VBA's WScript.Shell, wsl.exe is not found.

Comment: I want to launch cmd.exe from VBA's WScript.Shell or Shell, and then launch wsl.exe from cmd.exe.

Comment: What I really want to do is launch wsl.exe from VBA's WScript.Shell or Shell, and launch a shell script (e.g. my own vuln.sh) from wsl.exe.

Comment: What about launching `wsl.exe` directly with WScript?

Comment: Maybe you also have to consider [redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828782/6600940)

Comment: The cmd.exe called from VBS Shell is a 32-bit environment (WOW64).
Since wsl.exe executed from this cmd.exe is a 64-bit environment, wsl.exe was not displayed even if dir was executed. (Because of the file system redirector mechanism)

From the 32-bit version of cmd.exe, replace System32 in the WSL path with Sysnative and hit the dir command, and wsl.exe was displayed.

So wsl.exe was started with the answer code, and vuln.sh could be executed from here.
Thank you > @Storax

Answer (score 1):

```
' VBA
Private Sub RunBatShell(ByVal strPath As String)
    Dim dProcessId As Double

    BAT_FILE = strPath + "vuln.bat"

    dProcessId = Shell("cmd.exe /c;" & " " & BAT_FILE & " " & strPath, vbNormalFocus)

    If dProcessId = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Failed"
    End If

    ' MsgBox "Done"
End Sub



@echo off
REM Vuln.bat
REM 実行環境を引数でもらう
echo 引数： %1

REM echo > cd %1
cd %1

set PARAM=C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe ./vuln.sh
REM echo %PARAM%
cmd /c %PARAM%

REM echo Done
REM pause
```