# Open ODBC from button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2019 database and want to include a button to open the ODBC administrator. The event procedure on click is written as

```
Private Sub Command210_Click()
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("odbcad32.exe", 1)
End Sub
```

however this does not work, if I replace odbcad32.exe with notepad.exe it will open notepad on clicking but odbcad32 does not work - any ideas why?

Comment: There are 2 versions of odbcad32.exe - one for 32 bit in \syswow64 and one for 64 bit in \system32 - if you launch the exe from a X bit process then windows will redirect the request to the correct version - this seems not to work here. `Shell "cmd /c Odbcad32.exe"` will run the version that matches the bitness of you Access app although you also get a terminal window.

Comment: Thanks Alex - that works but is there any way to suppress or hide the terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of my previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828782/6600940) you could call the ODBC administrator like that

```
    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit
    
    Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
                            "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                            ByVal lpFile As String, _
                            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
                            
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection _
                            Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal Enable As Boolean) As Boolean
   
    Private Sub RunODBC_on64Bit()
        Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection False
        ShellExecute 0, "open", "odbcad32.exe", "", "C:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe", SW_SHOWNORMAL
        Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection True
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work - full code is:
Private Sub Command210_Click()
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("odbcad32.exe", 1)
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I got it in the end - I replaced line

RetVal = Shell("odbcad32.exe", 1)

with

RetVal = Shell("Explorer.exe ""C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe""", 1)

and that sorted it.