Trigger Keyboard Shortcut with VBA Macro
I want to open osk.exe. My company doesnt allow this by their security standards. But i can open it using a Keyboard-Shortcut. Is there a way to trigger this shortcut using Macros?
Like:
If Condition = True Then
    Press "Windows + Ctrl + O"
End If

Or something along the way?

Take a look at the SendKeys statement.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement
In your case SendKeys "^{O}" will simulate the keystrokes.

Just added the Windows into the code cause i forgot that one. I cant find anything about it in VBA

You might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826995/calling-on-screen-keyboard-from-excel-vba

That was my previous solution. I tried it and it worked but trying to save my file resulted in an error, which disabled my file. This solution sadly doesnt work with the security policy of my company. IT also told me to stop this.

You can do it using a single line of code:
  CreateObject("shell.application").ShellExecute "C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe", "", "", "open", 1

